# What does it mean exactly when Wikipedia calls Annihilationism a legitimate minority opinion within modern conservative Protestantism?

Tags: protestantism, demographics, annihilationism

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilationism#1900s_onwards) regarding Annihilationism states:
"Annihilationism seems to be gaining as a legitimate minority opinion within modern, conservative Protestant theology since the 1960s, and particularly since the 1980s."

This sentence condenses a lot of information. What does it mean exactly? How small or big is this minority? Does it look different in progressive theologies (whatever that would be)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia has a tendency to string adjectives together to form a description of something, usually after long and bitter debate on the talk pages.

What this sentence means is:

> **conservative Protestant theology**: this isn't a well-defined movement, but refers to the theology of non-Catholics who mostly hold to traditional Christian views. The adjective "modern" simply means those people who hold these views in recent times.

> **minority opinion**: most conservative Protestant believers don't hold to Annihilationism.

> **legitimate minority opinion**: holding to Annihilationism won't get you thrown out of the "conservative Protestant" group (ill-defined as that is)

Comment: Annihilationism is a belief in non-Protestant religions also. There's one (which shall remain nameless) which abhors being called either Protestant or Catholic but which claims to be the only 'true' Christian group, and it teaches soul-annihilation. Wiki ought to have detailed such complications (if it did not do so) but +1 for a good answer.